# disable dom changed event in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function()
    {}
```

to act whenever the DOM of the document is changed.

The problem is: In that function I modify the DOM myself but I do not want this change to call the DOMSubtreeModified-event (causing my code to be run over and over again)

Any chance to prevent that?

Comment: I would first try to fix the underlying problem that has you using that event.

Comment: ?!? Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: i've never seen that event used in a place where it wouldn't be better to instead use event delegation or similar methods such as pub/sub.

Comment: @OleAlbers you should trigger an event when using appending methods instead of a generic event like that.

Comment: Per the MDN on Mutation Events: This feature has been removed from the Web. Though some browsers may still support it, it is in the process of being dropped. Do not use it in old or new projects. Pages or Web apps using it may break at any time. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

Comment: This case is a bit "special" here. It is a chrome extension that modifies a foreign page (google+ to be precise). So I have to react, when the page displays new content

Comment: Copy `HTMLElement.prototype.appendChild` / `insertBefore`, wrap them in a _function_ which also dispatches a **custom event** to `this`, then use the originals for when you want the non-event-firing version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have done the same once using this solution:

```
function modifyDOM(obj){
    obj._muteTrigger = true;

    //HERE do your actual dom change

    obj._muteTrigger = false;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
    if(this._muteTrigger) return;

    //the other codes

    modifyDOM(this);
});
```